# How to recode a category within a variable using condition of another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, dplyr

I have two variables - Marital status (single, married, divorced), and Age (continuous). Marital status has a lot of NA's

I want to recode those with missing Marital Status (NA's) and aged <15 as single within the 'Marital Status' variable.

I have tried this using dplyr but no success

```
leanersharp %>% mutate(Marital.Status = case_when(Marital.Status== NA & Age <15 ~ 'Single'))
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a direct assignment -

```
df$Martial_Status[df$Age < 15 & is.na(df$Martial_Status)] <- 'Single'

#  Age Martial_Status
#1  10         Single
#2  23         Single
#3  34        Married
#4  45       Divorced
```

If you want to use `dplyr` and `case_when` -

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Martial_Status = case_when(Age < 15 & is.na(Martial_Status) ~ 'Single', 
                                    TRUE ~ Martial_Status))
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a reproducble format.

```
df <- data.frame(Age = c(10, 23, 34, 45), 
                 Martial_Status = c(NA, 'Single', 'Married', 'Divorced'))
df

#  Age Martial_Status
#1  10           <NA>
#2  23         Single
#3  34        Married
#4  45       Divorced
```